# Azure Service Principle

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am tring to create Service principal but each time facing this error :-

> Authenticating principal does not havepermission to instantiate
>   multi-tenantapplications and there is not matching Applicationin the
>   request tenant. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 194, in
>   invoke
>       cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py",
>   line 319, in execute
>       six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
>       raise value   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py",
>   line 292, in execute
>       result = cmd(params)   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py",
>   line 169, in **call**
>       return super(AzCliCommand, self).**call**(*args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/commands.py", line 109, in
>   **call**
>       return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/**init**.py", line
>   337, in default_command_handler
>       result = op(**command_args)   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/role/custom.py",
>   line 684, in create_service_principal_for_rbac
>       aad_sp = _create_service_principal(cmd.cli_ctx, app_id, resolve_app=False)   File
>   "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/role/custom.py",
>   line 525, in _create_service_principal
>       return client.service_principals.create(ServicePrincipalCreateParameters(app_id,
>   True))   File
>   "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/graphrbac/operations/service_principals_operations.py",
>   line 89, in create
>       raise models.GraphErrorException(self._deserialize, response) azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error.GraphErrorException: Authenticating
>   principal does not havepermission to instantiate
>   multi-tenantapplications and there is not matching Applicationin the
>   request tenant.

Comment: Not enough information provided in the question, it is not clear what you tried exactly

Comment: what command do you use?

Comment: If you use `az vm list`, what is the result?

Comment: Hi, any update about this?

Comment: this error resolved on its on I am still trying to replicate this

Comment: @BlindSniper Thanks for your reply, but it seems your cli version. Re-install it should solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error log, it seems your local Azure CLi version issue.

I suggest you could execute your command on [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview).

Also, you could use `az -v` to check the version of CLI. The latest version is `2.0.26`. If you don't use the latest version, you could re-install Azure CLI.